Lack of continuity across negative terminals
I am driving some solenoids (clippard) with a hit and hold circuit. Recently, my solenoids have stopped responding.
I have my solenoids wired such through a MCP23017 module so that they can be controlled by a raspberry pi. The wiring goes from the MCP23017 module NCD PR20-4, connected to a hit-and-hold module Instrument-In-A-Box, and then I have a flyback diode at the solenoid itself. The device has worked very well in this configuration for a while.
However, now the solenoids simply do not respond to my commands to turn on and my code shows no issues in sending the command so I believe there to be a hardware issue.
I have done some continuity testing with my multimeter, the positive terminal of the solenoid shows continuity all the way through, however, the negative terminal shows continuity from the flyback diode to the hit-and-hold module, but it does not show continuity across the hit-and-hold module.
Is there where my issue is at? How might I go about fixing this? What might have caused this problem to avoid repeating my issue?

Please show us a schematic (not a 1-line/block diagram) and photos of the actual setup.

@vir I updated the question to include the most recent photo that I have. How may I provide a schematic that can help? I have a lack of knowledge when it comes to drawing circuit diagrams from scratch. Most of my components are modules that I wire rather than build myself.

Are you sure, that its not just an empty battery? The missing continuity through the hit and hold module sounds plausible.

@Burglups each solenoid is 12V, typically have no more than 2 open at a time with a maximum of 4 open at a time. I'm unsure of the ohmic values across them. The diodes are 1N4007. Yes, they all stopped working at once, therefore I am thinking that it may be the MCP23017 module. I don't think the missing negative continuity through the hit and hold module is a problem anymore as these appear to be low sides and should not show continuity through the negative as per the manufacturer.

I was able to solve my issue. Turned out to be a couple of things.
Issue #1: There was a poor connection between the solar charge controller and the battery and this was leading to a ground fault causing the irregularly high loads that I seeing.
Issue #2: I had recently moved my device to a rooftop, on said rooftop, there is large EMF radiation from some equipment. This large EMF radiation was blocking my i2c communications and not allowing me to switch my solenoid valves or read my temperature sensor measurements. This was confirming by moving the device around the rooftop and having varying levels of success in switching the solenoids and reading the temperature measurements.
